# Disabling one app's cellular data inadvertently disabling other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data

I'm trying to get around a strange problem concerning an iOS app my company produces. We use a branding process to brand a single executable, assigning it new resources and a new bundle id, but keeping the same core executable across brands.

The problem is when a phone has multiple different brands installed, disabling one app for cellular connectivity is inadvertently disabling all of them, and I can't figure out why.

To reiterate, each app naturally has its own bundle id, so why would disabling cellular data for one app cause it to break for other brands?

Comment: What does your Cellular Data screen look like? Are the other apps still switched on?

Comment: @0942v8653 Yes, it just takes one being switched off to affect them all, even though they all appear enabled on the Cellular screen.

Comment: @chaiguy I'll look into this for you. I'll test out some different values in the `CellularUsage.db` database with apps from the same company and other things. Oh, and do you have any specific examples I could test with?

Comment: @AndrewLarsson That would be awesome, I really appreciate it. I will see if I can whip up some demo apps that exhibit the problem!

Comment: Future ref - this question is probably better asked at StackOverflow, as this site is for user questions not developer questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some further investigation and experimentation, and from what I can tell, iOS is identifying the disabled app based on the app *binary* in some fashion. That is, the actual embedded executable file inside the app bundle, instead of the bundle id as one would intuitively expect.

If I create two different builds, and brand them into several brands each, then disabling one of the branded apps disables cellular connectivity for all brands *in that group* (i.e. that share the same underlying binary), but do not affect those brands built with a different binary. Furthermore, renaming the embedded binary file has no effect, so it's clearly basing it on the contents of the executable (perhaps a checksum or internal identifier).

As far as I can tell this is just a bug in the implementation of this feature on iOS, and I can't think of any way around this that doesn't involve completely changing how we are branding our apps. I've submitted a bug report to Apple.